# Tinymce formatted content not displayed from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tinymce

Hi I have many tinymce editor in single page. When I format the content in tinymce and save it into database. All tags are saved in mysql. But while editing I get data from database but some of the tinymce (not all) is not able to read tags and it shows content without formatting. My initialization is:

```
  tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea", theme: "modern", width: "100%", height: 300,
        plugins: [
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code",
        "paste"
        ],
        paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
        toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
        toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
        image_caption: true,
        image_advtab: true,
        external_filemanager_path: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "tinymce/file_manager/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager",
        external_plugins: {"filemanager": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "tinymce/file_manager/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        document_base_url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",    
          relative_urls : false, 
          remove_script_host : false,
    });
```

Comment: How the data looks like when you are saving it into the database and ow does it look like when you get it back?

Comment: When I save in database I have content with tags but when I fetch I dont see any tags only text.

Comment: You must have some filtering/sanitizing in place for that field.

Comment: Oh.. yes. There was strip tags used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some sort of filtering or sanitizing.

You may have `strip_tags` used after you get the data from the database.